# Does the Duplicate Content penalty apply to mobile apps?

Tags: seo, google-workspace

Our website content and mobile app content are the same. Will Google assess a duplicate content penalty against our web site as a result of this?

Answer (score 5):

This depends on what you class as an "App" if you class a mobile version of your website i.e. m.yoursite.com then yes this will be classed as duplicate content. However, if you mean an app in the Google App Store then no this will not count as duplicate content. If you are however refering to the first, then this can be resolved easily using canonical and alternate links.

On the desktop page, add:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.example.com/page-1">
```

and on the mobile page, the required annotation should be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page-1">
```

This `rel="canonical"` tag on the mobile URL pointing to the desktop page is required.

Comment: But Google Play Store also index App, Suppose my Guru99 App https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vector.guru99&hl=en target testing keyword some time if you enter testing keyword into Google play Store our App rank display 87 Number and some time display 56 Number What is matter ? How Google Play store Rank Our app ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the content inside the mobile app is not indexed by Google.  The Google App search is a search of available apps in the Google Play store and the duplicate content penalty doesn't come into play here.

Comment: But Google Play Store also index App, Suppose my Guru99 App target testing keyword